# Terraform dynamic block issue in azure notification hub

Tags: azure

am trying to deploy the azure notification hub using terrafrom.

while integrating the google API token, if the token does not exist deployment is going to fail.
want deploy the notification hub with out the token for that using dyanamic block.

```
dynamic gcmcred {
    for_each = var.gcm_api == null ? [] : [ "dummy" ]
        content {
            gcm_credential {
            api_key  = var.gcm_api.token
        }
    }
}
```

below mentioned way declared the variable

```
variable "gcm_api" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [ "null" ]
}
```

am getting an issue like un supported block type

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
main.tf

locals {
  enable_gcm_credential = var.enable_gcm_credential ? [1] : []
}

resource "azurerm_notification_hub" "notification_hub" {
  name                = var.name
  namespace_name      = var.namespace_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location

  dynamic "gcm_credential" {
    for_each = local.enable_gcm_credential
    content {
      api_key = var.api_key
    }
  }
}
```

```
variables.tf

variable "enable_gcm_credential" {
  type = bool
  default = false
}
...
```